# Proving two norms are not equivalent

Tags: real-analysis

I have a vector space, $L$ which is the set of real sequences where there are only a finite number of non zero elements.

I want to prove these two norms on $L$ are not equivalent, $\|x\|=\sum |x_n|$ and  $\|x\|=max|x_n|$

Ive got really stuck trying to do this, so any help would be appreciated

Comment: Hint: consider the sequence (1,1,1,...,1,0,0,...) which has k 1's and all zeroes afterwards.

Comment: Look for a sequence which converges in one norm to $0$ but not in the other norm.

Comment: I don't understand how a sequence could be unbounded in either norm, because there is only a finite number of non zero values

Comment: If a sequence converges to 0 in one of the norms, surely it would converge to 0 in the other norm?

Comment: No, because we show, that the norms aren't equivalent.

Comment: But if the max of a sequence is 0, surely that would be the sum was zero also and vice versa

Answer (score 1):

Suppose $x_n$ is the sequence with $1$'s in the first $n$ slots and $0$'s elsewhere. Then the sum norm of $x_n$ is $n,$ while the max norm is $1.$ Thus there is no constant $C$ such that the sum norm is bounded above by $C$ times the max norm. Hence these two norms are not equivalent on $L.$

Answer (score 0):

The sequence of sequences with $\frac{1}{k}$ for the first $k$ entries and $0$ for the others, converges in the $\max$-norm to $(0,0,\dotsc)$ but it doesn't converge in the $\sum$-norm, because there is the norm of the sequences always $1$.

Comment: I'm really confused, sorry. I don't see why it doesn't converge for both norms. There are only a finite number of non zero values in any sequence, so surely both norms would converge

Comment: Not the norms converge but the sequences converge to another sequence.

Comment: But how does this show the norms are not equivalent?

Comment: How do you define equivalent norms?

Comment: $||x||_1$ And  $||x||_2$ are equivalent if there exists $k_1 and k_2$ where $k_1||x||_1\le||x||_2\le k_2||x||_1$

Comment: $k_1 and k_2$ are greater than 0

Comment: And so iff the norm gets small in one norm it has to get small in the other, especially if something converges in one norm it converges in the other.

Comment: So how how can I show that the norms fail to the definition of equivalence

Comment: When you show there is one sequence which converges in one norm and not in the other, you've done by the argument above.

Comment: I don't understand how it's about sequences converging. Surely it's about the norms converging?